# Why is this 254.63.0.1, not a valid host address?

Tags: ip, subnet, ip-address

Getting the below error, when trying to configure the ip address 254.63.0.1 as an SVI.

```
Switch(config)#interface vlan 254

Switch(config-if)#ip address 254.63.0.1 255.255.0.0

Not a valid host address - 254.63.0.1

Switch(config-if)#
```

Not sure what am I doing wrong?
Or is this some special ip address?

Answer (score 2):

240.0.0.0/4 is reserved by ARIN (*SPECIAL-IPV4-FUTURE-USE-IANA-RESERVED*). Likely, the switch is rejecting that address because it's part of the pre-1993 *class E* address range. Many hosts and devices reject that address range as source and even as destination address.

https://search.arin.net/rdap/?query=254.63.0.1

You cannot just use IP addresses unless you are either explicitly entitled to or they are free to use privately (esp. [RFC 1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918): 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16).

Of course, you can do what you want inside your own, private network but any address collision will prevent proper routing with an Internet connection.